# Row sum of square matrix $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$ relation to row/column sum of $\mathbf{A}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ with positive entries. Its column sum is $k$ and its row sum is $1$, i.e. $\sum col(\mathbf{A}) = k$ and $\sum row(\mathbf{A}) = 1$.

Now looking at $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}$, I notice that it has a row (and column) sum of $k$, i.e. $\sum row(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}) = \sum col(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}) = k$. Is there a reason for this?

Could this be because $\sum row(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}) = \sum col(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}) = \sum col(\mathbf{A})*\sum row(\mathbf{A})$?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean the sums are vectors in $\Bbb R^m$ and $\Bbb R^n$ with entries $k$ and $1$ (respectively) only?

Comment: It's the other way around, so the sums are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ with entries $1$ and $k$ respectively only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u$ be the column vector of $n$ $1$'s and $v$ the column vector of $m$ $1$'s.
The column vector of row sums of $A$ is $A u$ and the row vector of column sums is 
$v^T A$.  You seem to be saying that $v^T A = k u^T$ and $A u = v$.  Then
$A^T A u = A^T v = (v^T A)^T = k u^T$ and $u^T A^T A = (A u)^T A = v^T A = k u$, so the row and column sums of $A^T A$ are all $k$.

Comment: That appears to be what I was looking for! Thank you. If there is theorem that shows this relation, that would also be helpful.